# Why willDisplay is called multiple times in for collectionView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I am using collectionView with pagination but the willDisplay method is called multiple times I don't know why. If anybody has some idea please help me out....................................................

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    guard gridCollectionView!.contentOffset.y >= (gridCollectionView!.contentSize.height - gridCollectionView!.bounds.size.height),
          !isRefreshing else { return }
    isRefreshing = !isRefreshing
    offset += limit
    
    getAllExcrcise(keyword: "", limit: limit, offset: offset)
    
}
```

API calling function

```
func getAllExcrcise(keyword: String = "", limit: Int = 10, offset: Int = 0, clearAll:Bool = false) {
    
    if clearAll {
        self.allExcercise.removeAll()
    }
    
    var params = [String: Any]()
    params = [
                "keyword": keyword,
                "limit": limit,
                "offset": offset,
                "muscle" : bodyPartSelectedArr,
                "equipment": categorySelectedArr
        
             ]
    
    WebServiceHelper.postWebServiceCall(Constants.baseURL + "getAllExcercises", params: params, isShowLoader: true, success: { (responceObj) in
        
        let statusMsg = GetAllExcerciseLevelOneData(json: responceObj)
        
        if statusMsg.status {
            let respArr = responceObj["data"].arrayValue
            for item in respArr {
                let dataModel = GetAllExcercise(json: item)
                
                for selectedVal in self.selectedItem {
                    if selectedVal.id == dataModel.id {
                        dataModel.isCellSelected = true
                    }
                }
                
                self.allExcercise.append(dataModel)
            }
            self.totalPages = statusMsg.totalPages
        } else {
            //CommonUtils.showToastMessage(message: statusMsg.message ?? "")
        }
        
        self.tableView?.reloadData()
        self.gridCollectionView?.reloadData()
    }
   , failure: { (failure) in
        print(failure)
   })
}
```

Comment: willDisplay method call before each cell load in table/collection view

Comment: so how would I acheive pagination

Comment: You can use UIScrollViewDelegate.

Comment: can you plz explain with code

Comment: You want to achieve pagination for which scroll direction ?

Comment: vertical........

Comment: I answered the question and in it have mentioned for both direction. Have a look at it.

Comment: And can you please update the question statement to be more precise as want to achieve infinite scrolling.

Comment: You need to track the highest index you have fetched (initially this is say, 10, call this `fetched`).  Then in `willDisplay` you check the index path.  If it is `fetched-2` then you set `fetched=fetched+10` and issue a fetch for the next 10 rows.  Once the rows are returned you can append them to the array and call `insertItems(at indexPaths)` to add the items to your collection view.  Don't reload the whole thing

Comment: What you actually want to achieve? Why you are calling api call in willDisplay? Isn't it what you want to achieve that when you scroll up api will fetch items when you about to reach at the last item ?

Answer (score 0):

`willDisplay cell:` is called before each of your cell in `UICollectionView` is displayed and visible to user. If the cell is going out of the presented view (lets say that user swiped to another cell) , the systems calls `didEndDisplaying didEndDisplayingCell:` function.

Answer (score 0):

you can check current index of cell which is going to be display in *willDisplay* method and if its last index of array than you have to call for *getNextPageData*. while data is being fetched you can show loading indicator which shows data loading currently in-progress.